# Problema en javascript con sistema de medidas en tabla

Tags: php, javascript, html, datatables

Estoy comenzando a aprender un poco de javascript para hacer un pequeño proyecto y me he topado con un problema que no he podido resolver de ninguna manera, espero me puedan ayudar.

- Les comento un poco sobre el proyecto para saber de que va: En una
  tabla incrementable se piden una medidas [largo][ancho][alto] y
  adicional a esto se pide el [peso] y la [cantidad]. Tras unos
  cálculos se obtienen [PesoTotal] [VolumenTotal]
- Al final se deben tener 2 resultados [Totales] distintos.
- El resultado que se va a alojar en: [TotalAirUSD] se debe calcular de
  la siguiente manera -> comparar el [PesoTotal] y [VolumenTotal] para
  saber cuál es el MAYOR entre los dos  y guardar su valor en una
  variable (var), luego: si la variable es MAYOR a 8 (var > 8) debe
  mutiplicarse por la variable tarifa (var * rate) para dar como
  resultado [TotalAirUSD] - De lo contrario [TotalAirUSD] se le asigna
  un valor de 20.
- He aquí el problema: si se introduce uno de estos números "4 5 6 7 8" en el campo [Peso] entonces [TotalAirUSD] toma un valor de 20 automaticamente (con el resto de los números funciona bien)

**Proyecto completo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/irvingngr/yna66sa3/

**Proyecto simplificado al problema:**
https://jsfiddle.net/irvingngr/y3x5x27v/

- Notas: Cuando ingreso algun valor en "**Weight Total (totalweight)**"
  mutiplica por el valor de "**Air Rate**" y devuelve el resultado en
  "**Total Air USD**" Excepto cuando ingreso alguno de estos numeros: 4
  , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 no cumple la condicion "IF > 8" y automaticamente
  pasa a valor total de "20"

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco dificil leer el código ya que tiene varios errores, en la parte del html te marca en rojo los errores, por ejemplo, en la siguiente línea abres un tag  pero nunca lo cierras

```
<th width="10%"><center>Length</th>
```

En la linea 123 del html estas cerrando un form que nunca se abrió

En cuanto al javascript en las lineas 88,89 y 90 estas llamando al metodo html() en lugar de val(), lo que hace html es traer el código html de los nodos hijos y val obtiene el valor del atributo value

```
totalweightvariable = $('#totalweight').html();
airtotalvar = $('#airtotal').html();
air = $('#airrate').html();
```

En la linea 88, totalweightvariable trae undefined ya que no existe ningun elemento con el id **totalweight**

Te recomiendo ir poniendo algunos console.log para ir checando los valores que llegan, pero recuerda borrarlos cuando todo ya esté bien, por ejemplo:

```
totalweightvariable = $('#totalweight').html();
console.log(totalweightvariable ); //imprime undefined
airtotalvar = $('#airtotal').html();
console.log(airtotalvar ); //cadena vacía
air = $('#airrate').html();
console.log(air ); //cadena vacía
```

Al final tendría que quedar así

```
totalweightvariable = $('#totalweight').val(); //Solo asegurate que exista un elemento con id=totalweight
airtotalvar = $('#airtotal').val();
air = $('#airrate').val();
```

**EDITO**
Ya con el error simplificado es más  fácil ver el problema, lo que pasa es que estas comparando strings, val() te regresa un string aunque sean numeros y hay que pasarlos a float

```
totalwvariable =parseFloat(document.querySelector('#totalweight').value);
airtotalvar = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#airtotal').value);
air = parseFloat($('#airrate').val());
```

Cuando compara strings va caracter por caracter si tienes "35" y lo comparas contra "4" primero compara el "3" contra el "4" y como cumple que 4 es mayor a 3 entraba al if

Comment: Hola Lato, muchisimas gracias por responder, si, estoy consciente de que habian varios errores minimos pero los corregi y no cambio en nada.

Comment: He agregado una porcion del codigo al post, simplificando mi duda, podrias ayudarme por favor?

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta espero esa sea la solución definitiva